# shorewall logging, but not to syslog

Tags: linux, logs, shorewall

I have a Debian 9.1 installation I'm using as a NAT router.  Shorewall version 5.0.15.6-1, linux kernel version 4.9+80+deb9u1.  There are two network interfaces.  The routing functions are all working correctly.

I would like to log connections and rejections to a log file, but not via syslog, as *everything* else goes there.  I've read http://shorewall.org/shorewall_logging.html and followed it as well as I may, and other documents I've found are all about peripheral cases.  However, my ulog log file is empty, and netfilter msgs are still going to /var/log/kern.log.

here are some excerpts from relevant config files:

/etc/shorewall/params

```
ETH1=br1
LOG="NFLOG(1,,)"
```

/etc/shorewall/shorewall.conf

```
LOGFILE=/var/log/shorewall-run.log
LOGFORMAT="Shorewall:%s:%s:"
MACLIST_LOG_LEVEL=$LOG
RPFILTER_LOG_LEVEL=$LOG
SFILTER_LOG_LEVEL=$LOG
SMURF_LOG_LEVEL=$LOG
STARTUP_LOG=/var/log/shorewall-init.log
TCP_FLAGS_LOG_LEVEL=$LOG
```

/etc/shorewall/rules

```
ACCEPT:$LOG          loc                        $FW                        tcp     5509
ACCEPT:$LOG          net                        $FW                        tcp     5509
ACCEPT               loc                        $FW                        udp     53
ACCEPT               loc                        $FW                        tcp     53
```

the /etc/ulogd.conf is stock, it's the same as from /usr/share/doc/ulogd2/examples/ulogd.conf.gz

I'm not getting any compilation errors when I run shorewall restart, and, as in the rules sample above, I am getting syslog messages for connections to 5509, but not 53.  The log entries are just going to the wrong place.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

According to `man shorewall.conf`

```
LOGFILE=[pathname|systemd]
    This parameter tells the /sbin/shorewall program where to look
    for Shorewall messages when processing the dump, logwatch, show
    log, and hits commands.
```

So changing this parameter does not affect the place where your firewall will write its log messages to.

If you want to configure Shorewall to direct Netfilter messages to a log facility other than `syslog`, you might want consult `man shorewall-logging` for the various options to achieve this.